# MEJS ignoring preload tag after setSrc()

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js, preload

howdy ~ tryin' to whip out a MEJS based video player with user switchable vids.

problem i'm havin is when i call `setSrc()`, both the flash and the html5 player preloads the entire video before it starts playing the new vid, regardless of what the `preload` tag indicates.  ideally the video begins playing as data is downloading.

```
/* code and comments trimmed for your viewing pleasure */
<video src="myvideo1.mp4" width="800" height="450" preload="none" smoothing autoplay></video>

<script>
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('video', {
        enablePluginDebug: true,
        plugins: ['flash','silverlight'],
        defaultVideoWidth: 800, defaultVideoHeight: 450,
        videoWidth: -1, videoHeight: -1,
        loop: false,
        features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','fullscreen'], 
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
            mediaElement.play();
        },
        error: function () { 
            alert('error!');
        }
    });

    var currentVid = 1;

    var vidnames = new Array("(null)",
        "myvideo1.mp4",
        "myvideo2.mp4",
        "myvideo3.mp4");

    function switchvid (vidnum) {
        currentVid = vidnum;

        player.pause();
        player.setSrc( vidnames[vidnum] );
        player.play();

        return false;
    }

</script>

<A HREF="#" onClick="return switchvid(1)"><IMG SRC="ch01x.png"></A>
<A HREF="#" onClick="return switchvid(2)"><IMG SRC="ch02x.png"></A>
<A HREF="#" onClick="return switchvid(3)"><IMG SRC="ch03x.png"></A>
```

tried `preload="none"`, `preload`, `preload="auto"` all with the same results... player just appears to hang while filling the buffer with the entire download, then begins to play.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the load() function handles this.  not clear on load()'s relationship to the PRELOAD attributes (if any), but for me it is working now.

```
 var player = new MediaElementPlayer('video', {
    // etc
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.load();
        mediaElement.play();
    }
 }

function switchvid (vidnum) {
    currentVid = vidnum;

    player.pause();
    player.setSrc( vidnames[vidnum] );
    player.load();
    player.play();

    return false;
}
```